# To print sum of numbers from this string

Tags: php, string

asked in interview, how to print a sum of numbers from this string
i tried sum basics but didn't worked.

$str= "Welcome 13,14,15,ab16,14ab";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this to separate text and number first then proceed further,

```
preg_match_all('/[^\d]+/', $string, $textMatch);
preg_match('/\d+/', $string, $numMatch);

$text = $textMatch[0];
$num = $numMatch[0];
```

Comment: instead of making minus rating can anybody tell where i was wrong

Comment: the second preg_match() supposed to be preg_match_all() too